# Is there a way to set concurrency in a linux EC2 instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

I currently have a script inside a linux ec2 instance that processes some documents. This script gets called from AWS Lambda using (SSM) `send_command`. It works fine when it processes one or two documents but when it gets past that, I get empty responses. Im assuming the system bottlenecks as there is essentially no limit to the amount of calls that I can send to the instance. So is there a way to set the concurrency level on the instance to only process say 2 commands at a time?

I know I can set the concurrency level on the lambdas, but the execution time is usually less than 200ms. Meanwhile the processing time in the instance is about 5 to 15 seconds.

Ultimately, I can have the lambdas wait for the job to be completed but it would be expensive as I need to process thousands of documents.

Thank you!

Comment: I would reconsider your overall design if you are using SSM send_command for something other than system administration. AWS batch or ECS fargate tasks are examples of more suitable alternatives.

Comment: DefaultCommandWorkersLimit     https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/blob/master/agent/appconfig/constants.go#L26 is the setting you are looking for may be